# Problem in Saving Multi Level Models in YII

Tags: php, yii, yii-cmodel

My Table structure for user and his adress detail is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_users (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  loginname varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  enabled enum("True","False"),
  approved enum("True","False"),
  password varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  role_id int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  name varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  co_type enum("S/O","D/O","W/O") DEFAULT "S/O",
  co_name varchar(70),
  gender enum("MALE","FEMALE","OTHER") DEFAULT "MALE",
  dob date DEFAULT NULL,
  maritalstatus enum("SINGLE","MARRIED","DIVORCED","WIDOWER") DEFAULT "MARRIED",
  occupation varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  occupationtype_id int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  occupationindustry_id int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  contact_id bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  signupreason varchar(500),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY loginname (loginname),
  UNIQUE KEY email (email),
  FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES tbl_roles (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (occupationtype_id) REFERENCES tbl_occupationtypes (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (occupationindustry_id) REFERENCES tbl_occupationindustries (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES tbl_contacts (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE tbl_contacts (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  contact_type enum("cres","pres","coff"),
  address varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  landmark varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  district_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  city_id int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  state_id int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  pin_id bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  area_id bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  po_id bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  phone1 varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  phone2 varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  mobile1 varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  mobile2 varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (district_id) REFERENCES tbl_districts (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES tbl_cities (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES tbl_states (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE tbl_states (
  id int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE tbl_districts (
  id int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  state_id int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES tbl_states (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE tbl_cities (
  id int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  district_id int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  state_id int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (district_id) REFERENCES tbl_districts (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES tbl_states (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The relationship is as follows
User has multiple contacts i.e Permanent Address, Current Address, Office Address.
Each Contact has state and City.

User->Contact->state like this

How to save models of this structure in one go.

Please provide a reply ASAP

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had a similar issue saving a multi leveled model with many foreign keys.  It doesn't seem that it can easily be saved in 'one go'...
Take a look at [my solution here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/4472-forms-with-db-normalization-and-dynamic-fields/page__view__findpost__p__23817)

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at gii-templates extension on google code -

[gii templates on google code](http://code.google.com/p/gii-template-collection/)

->> It might be documented better, but it attempts to do what you need.
(It might save you some time if you implement it well, but I'd even consider hand-coding it
if I were you.)